# Issues with translation contribution

Tags: translation

I was thinking of contributing to some translation to Norwegian. The problem is that it's impossible for me to create an account at the elementary weblate site. When I try to create an account, I never receive a confirmation email. When I click the "Report an issue with registration" button, I just get a server error message after filling out the form. I tried a month ago as well, and this still hasn't been fixed. What can I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest you join their Slack-based chat from the white button on the left shown at [their Translations page](https://elementary.io/get-involved#translations) and ask for help. Open Source projects sometimes drop the ball, certainly not an issue limited to Elementary OS.

Thank you for volunteering to help!

Comment: I will do. Thanks.